# JavaMail throws odd exception on Azure platform but works on Linux

Tags: java, azure, jakarta-mail

I'm working on a Java web application that uses JavaMail. I'm trying to send an outgoing mail using a Gmail account. I configured JavaMail to use smtp.gmail.com as the host and 587 as the port.

My test environment is an Linux server on Amazon EC2. In the test environment it works fine.

My production environment is a Windows server running on Azure. In that environment, it fails with this exception:

2016-01-14 09:55:31,406 Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;

What I can't figure out is why it is reporting localhost and 25 as the host and port. I'm sure I am configuring these correctly because it works on the Linux server (and the values are hard-coded in the source code, so I'm not losing them by virtue of some missing property file or environment variable).

Frank

Comment: Perhaps you're making one of these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes)?  If not, show us your code and the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

Answer (score 0):

On Azure, the outgoing rule of NSGs deny the internel accessing, please see the pic below from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/.

[image]

So the application on Azure VM can not directly send email via GMail, but you can use `SendGrid` to do it. You can refer to the doc [How to Send Email Using SendGrid with Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email/) to know it.

If you have to send email by using your application, you can try to configure the outgoing rule for NSG to allow Internet accessing. Please refer to the section `How to create the NSG for the back end subnet` of the doc [How to create NSGs in the Azure CLI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-cli/#how-to-create-the-nsg-for-the-back-end-subnet%20to) or [How to create NSGs in PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-ps/#how-to-create-the-nsg-for-the-back-end-subnet).

Or you can try to directly add the outbound security rule by refering to [How to manage NSGs using the preview portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal/#create-rules-in-an-existing-nsg) on the Azure new portal.

Otherwise, please check the Windows Server firewall was enable the bound rule, please see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj717286.aspx for how to create an outbound role.